# Excel changes cell formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work with an Excel file approx. 10,000 rows on each of 12 sheets. This file is used quite a bit to pull data from (i.e. sorted, filtered, changed manually) but I never tamper with the columns that contain the formulae.

Over the past couple of weeks I've been noticing that some of the reference values within the cells have been changing. The only reason I saw this is because excel gracefully points out when a formula is different from the ones above and below it (with the small green arrows). Up to this point I've just gone and click "Restore to column formula".

Example:

`=IFERROR(IF(G148/E148>100%,100%,G148/E148),"")`

had been changed to,

`=IFERROR(IF(G157/E157>100%,100%,G157/E157),"")`

*while still in Row 148.*

Now this isn't a large pain to go and change all the values, its typically < 100 values. But I'm fearing the day this turns into over 9000 values.

My goal is to find out the root cause of this problem and nullify it from continuing to happen. I am using Excel 2010.

**EDIT:** This is an example of the problem I'm speaking about. The reference rows **should** continue in order, but you'll notice row 337, 341, and 345 have all changed to different rows (209, 224, 158 respectively).

[image: Issue at hand.]

Comment: A new row would be inserted manually, and the formula copied down to populate existing columns. At that time the formula would be referencing the correct row number.

Comment: Are you the only person who uses this sheet? Is there a chance that anyone could be dragging cells around or cutting and pasting them anywhere? If any of the cells your formulas are pointing at are moved in this way the reference will move with them.

Comment: If you **insert** a row, the formulas below will be changed to reflect their new location. If you **add** a row at the bottom, this will not occur.  Are you really doing an **insertion** and don't want the cells below to reflect their new location? IF so, then you may need to use the INDIRECT function.

Comment: @Dave - I am not the only person to use this sheet, however I am the only person to update it. Generally if I copy and paste formula data around I check that it is inline after the paste.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld - No, if I do an insertion I'd prefer the row reference change. However that's not the case this time. I haven't inserted any new rows into the table, yet the references change from time to time.

Can this be caused by working with data while it is filtered? I'm going to try to get an example posted.

Comment: @ColeLange I suppose that depends on the details of exactly what you are doing when you are "working with the data".  But I've not seen Excel change cell formulas willy-nilly.  So there must be something you are someone else is doing to change things. In the instance in your OP, it looks as if 9 rows had been inserted.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld - If 9 rows were inserted and it referenced row 157, that would be great, the problem is it's referencing row 157 while still in row 148. I'll edit the question to try and make that more clear.

Comment: @ColeLange I didn't mean to imply that 9 rows were **actually** inserted; just that the formula was acting that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58498/discussion-between-cole-lange-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.

I tried to replicate the problem instead of waiting for it to happen again and I found that this was occuring because I was filtering data in the table, and then sorting it. The reason numbers are so random is that the filter would grab only a handful of rows from thousands, and then sorting it would change the cell reference.

With that being said, I believe this post is now a copy of the following: [How do I sort a table in Excel if it has cell references in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979923/how-do-i-sort-a-table-in-excel-if-it-has-cell-references-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this, is to use Excel's built in tables feature. With this much data it may not be feasible, but one benefit, is that when you have a formula it doesn't reference the row number, it instead just has the formula use the data in the same row as the formula.

Not very clear. Let's try again

I have a table

```
col1    col2    col3
1       2
2       4
```

in col3 I want a sum of the items of the same row in col1 and col2.

Without the table feature in Excel I would have the following formulas in the table

```
=A2+B2
=A3+B3
```

With the table feature in Excel the formula looks like this.

```
=[col1]+[col2]
=[col1]+[col2]
```

The formula is the same for all rows, and the table knows to use the same row of data.