# Sorting formulas issue

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, formula

I have a table which consists of names (1st column) avarageifs (2-6 columns) and average formulas (7 column).

### [image: Table before sorting]

Averageifs formula is taking the name to average values for each name:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Grades!B:B,Grades!$A:$A,Rankings!$B14),"N/A")
```

"Total" average formula is:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(C14:G14),0)
```

Then I am trying to sort it by "total" average, formulas are mixing up and referring to different rows.

### [image: Table after sorting]

But it should refer to the same row. What happens after sorting and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try using table for all of your table https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca

Comment: @Linga thank you, but converting into table didn't help..

Comment: @pnuts `Grades` - is another tab in this workbook, and `Rankings` is a tab there the table is located.

Comment: @pnuts ok, as I said in `Rankings` tab there is a table we are talking about and formula is referring to the name in the same row. In `Grades` tab in column "A" there are few lists of the same names and next to names there are columns containing rankings I am transferring. Basically `Grades` is a data-sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the references in the AVERAGEIFS formulae are getting swapped around and you don't want this to happen.

The easiest way round it would be to put the Totals column next to the Names column and just sort these two columns, leaving the other formulae in place.

If you don't want to do that, a fairly quick and dirty solution is to replace the AVERAGEIFS formulae with this so they always refer to the current row:-

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Grades!B:B,Grades!A:A,INDIRECT("Rankings!$B"&ROW())),"N/A")
```

See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979923/how-do-i-sort-a-table-in-excel-if-it-has-cell-references-in-it)