# When I use a macro to sort, all references become #REF

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula, excel-2010

I built a macro which would automatically sort a large section of cells for me every time I trigger it. Unfortunately, when I run this macro, many of my references are changed from their original (i.e. $B$7) to #REF!. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my macro script or if there is something else I should be looking into. Here's the code:

```
Sub Sort()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(_
        "Q8:Q1000000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=_
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("Q8:W1000000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Row 7 is unaffected by this script, both in concept and in execution

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the code...  my guess is it has to do with the content.  Can you share some of the values/formulas involved or even attach an abbreviated version of the spreadsheet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This [SO Sort Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979923/how-do-i-sort-a-table-in-excel-if-it-has-cell-references-in-it) may help you.

Comment: I've read that if the name of the worksheet is used in the formula, you should remove it if you're going to be sorting the results.

Comment: Before sorting most of the formulas follow the format of =IF(ISBLANK(M11),NA(),M11) and after they say IF(ISBLANK(#REF!),NA(),#REF!).

Comment: The formulas do not contain the name of the spreadsheet

Comment: Found out that absolute references do not change into #REF!. I found a script online to cycle reference types for large selections, and I'm testing that now. If it works I'll update and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It isn't ideal, though it worked. I changed all my references to absolute, and now when I sort they no longer become the strange null reference #REF!. Given that there were 7 million formulas to edit, I used a macro I found [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/74802-change-multiple-formula-range-references-between-absolute-relative) to speed up the process a lot. Macro provided by mikerickson.

If anyone knows of another solution that is better than necessarily changing all references, feel free to leave an answer for others who may have the same question, though I no longer need any guidance on this issue.

Thanks