# Sort doesn't work if sheetname is included in formula (Excel)

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a problem with sorting in Excel and I cant find out why.
I have two tables which need sorting by a formula field (Field4 in the below image).

Basically, the formulas in two fields of these table are almost same. But for the first one, I use 'sheetname'!CellAddress ref and CellAddress ref only for the other.

I'd like to sort by Field4 (smallest to largest). Here is the result after sorting:
[image]

For the first case, it doesn't work and the formulas in Field4 are changed. For the second one, it's okay.

Could you please help me explain. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979923/how-do-i-sort-a-table-in-excel-if-it-has-cell-references-in-it. Same behavior is mentioned in the second answer. Don't use sheet references.

Comment: @BigBen do you have any ideas why?