# Can't sort the column alphabetically in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, ms-office

I have a sheet in which I want to sort the email column alphabetically. The issue is that excel is sorting the column multiple times for example look in the image below. It sorts up to row 13 then some values start with numbers then start sorting again from A to Z. Even if I remove the values starting from numbers in between it stills sorts from A to Z then sorts again from row 15 as you can see in the 2nd image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue - I've used same names as you in 'show email as' option with various email addresses, sorted manually (excel: data: sort) and likewise with sort function (Office 365) and my sorted lists work fine.  How are you sorting exactly and what does the function bar show when you select any of the anomalies in your ('attempted') sorted lists?

Comment: How are the email entered?  Are they copy/pasted/entered directly?  Or are they the result of some formula?  If so, see [Sort a table in Excel if it has cell references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979923/how-do-i-sort-a-table-in-excel-if-it-has-cell-references-in-it)

Comment: Show, or spell out, the step by step process that you are using to attempt to sort.  
Also, specify any formatting in the email column, or any formatting in any individual email column.  
Also, specify the file type that you are saving the worksheet as.